# Fallo en menú responsive bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

estoy construyendo un menú que debe ser responsive. El menú (Que es mostrado a través de un include en php) se ejecuta en principio bien, tanto en visión grande, como en pequeña. El problema está en que cuando estoy en la página de la opción de inicio (URL como veis es varios/inicio.php), el menú en vista móvil funciona perfectamente, se despliegan los submenús sin problema. Cuando cambio y estoy en otra página (Por ejemplo, facturas/listar.php) se despliega el menú de ventas, pero no el de facturas, cuando pulso en facturas se cierra la opción de ventas. ¿Sabeis porque en una ventana se ejecuta bien y en la otra no? .Como nota utilizo bootstrap 4

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav id="topbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav theme-brand flex-row  text-center">
    <li class="nav-item theme-logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="assets/img/90x90.jpg" class="navbar-logo" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item theme-text">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">Gestión</a> </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list-unstyled menu-categories" id="topAccordion">

    <li class="menu single-menu active">
      <a href="varios/inicio.php" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle autodroprown">
        <div class="">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-home">
            <path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path>
            <polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline>
          </svg>
          <span onclick="window.location.href='../varios/inicio.php';">Inicio</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu single-menu">
      <a href="#facturas" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <div class="">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-activity">
            <path d="M12.89 1.45l8 4A2 2 0 0 1 22 7.24v9.53a2 2 0 0 1-1.11 1.79l-8 4a2 2 0 0 1-1.79 0l-8-4a2 2 0 0 1-1.1-1.8V7.24a2 2 0 0 1 1.11-1.79l8-4a2 2 0 0 1 1.78 0z"></path>
            <polyline points="2.32 6.16 12 11 21.68 6.16"></polyline>
            <line x1="12" y1="22.76" x2="12" y2="11"></line>
            <line x1="7" y1="3.5" x2="17" y2="8.5"></line>
          </svg>
          <span>Ventas</span>
        </div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-down">
          <polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <ul class="collapse submenu list-unstyled" id="facturas" data-parent="#facturas">
        <li class="sub-sub-submenu-list">
          <a href="#facturasdes" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Facturas
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-right">
              <polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled sub-submenu" id="facturasdes" data-parent="#facturas">
            <li>
              <a href="facturas/listar.php">Listar Facturas</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="facturas/listar_ptes.php">Facturas Ptes</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="caja/caja.php">Ver mi Caja</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: no entiendo bie la pregunta pero si lo que dices es que la vista se "daña o desordena" creo que se debe a algun div mal cerrado o algo por el estilo si usas vscode puedes instalar alguna extension que revise esa estructura

Comment: A lo mejor me he explicado regular. El menú lo cargo mediante un include en php. Si estoy cargandolo desde varios/inicio.php el menú funciona correctamente (En versión responsive (Visto desde el movil) se abren todos los submenus). Si lo abro desde cualquier otra ruta (Por ejemplo facturas/listar.php) en responsive (Visto desde el movil) Solo se abre la primera opción del menú (En este caso ventas). Cuando pulso en el siguiente sub-menú (Facturas) no se abre y se cierra el menú de ventas.

Comment: Puedes crear un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para poder ejecutar el código en la pregunta misma. Si lo haces, no olvides agregar la librería de Bootstrap (así de paso se sabe qué versión de BS estás utilizando).

Comment: Ok, ya lo he hecho y edito la pregunta incluyendo que uso Bootstrap 4.

Comment: He editado tu pregunta, pues ese desorden que se veia era porque uno de los <script> no estaba cerrado y se volvia loco reordenando las cosas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, muchas gracias a todos. Explico la solución:

1)-En primer lugar, en la visual donde fallaba tenía un div sin cerrar
2)-Este no lo entiendo, pero he verificado que es así. Si la visual tiene una tabla, daba el fallo y no se abría el menú, pero al quitar la clase table de la tabla, servía.

Solo con eso ha quedado arreglado. Lo dicho, gracias a todos.